# Passing viewbag result to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Viewbag that is populated with user roles in my Get register, then in my view I display the dropdown for all users. When someone chooses the role I want to save the id from, the user and from the role to the aspNetUserRoles but somehow I dont know why I cant pass the result from my dropdown back to my controller :S

**I have this:**

**Register Get controller**

```
 public ActionResult Register()
 {
     ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Id", "Name"); return View();
 }
```

**Register View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Tipo de utilizador", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Role", ViewBag.Roles as SelectList, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" } )
    </div>
</div>
```

**Register Get**

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Sobre = model.Sobre, Idade = model.Idade, Telemóvel = model.Telemóvel, Nome = model.Nome };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);


            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Role");
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I just want to receive the `RoleId` and add it to the roles database with the user associate to it, how can i do that? and I want to use the default tables created by asp.net like `aspNetUserRole` and `aspNetRole`

Comment: You have a dropdownlist named `"Role"` so assuming your view model has a property `int Role`, then that property will be bound with the selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify Your Model as

```
public class ApplicationUser 
{
   public int RoleId{get;set;}
   ///////Remain Column Here in ApplicationUser model
}
```

At View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Tipo de utilizador", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.RoleId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles, "Id", " Name"), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" } )
</div>
```

Register Get

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Sobre = model.Sobre, Idade = model.Idade, Telemóvel = model.Telemóvel, Nome = model.Nome };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db);
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);


        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.RoleId);
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```